# When is fragment finally attached to activity?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have a main fragment with a viewpager inside it. This viewpager has 2 pages (list fragments). When I start the activty, the main fragment is shown and I also show the first paged fragment. This paged fragment displays data from a db using `AsyncTask`.

In the main fragment I have:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    onPageSelected(0);
}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    Fragment fragment = (Fragment) pagerAdapter.instantiateItem(viewPager, position);
    if (fragment instanceof IPagedFragment) {
        ((IPagedFragment) fragment).onShown(getActivity());
    }
}
```

And the interface is:

```
public interface IPagedFragment {
    void onShown(FragmentActivity activity);
}
```

The first issue I have is that I have to pass the activity as a parameter because when `onShown` gets called, the activity is still null.

Furthermore, the paged fragments use progressbar logic similar to the LoginActivity sample. I also get the following exception:

> IllegalStateException: Fragment PagedFragment1{4201f758} not attached to Activity 
>   at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.getResources(Fragment.java:620)

So what is the correct stage to start retrieving data from db once the paged fragment is fully available to the UI?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Issues like yours is the reason some developers are starting to question if fragments are really that good or useful.

Also "the correct" is debatable as you can do it in a variety of places and different developers will give you different answers, But let me try to supply you some useful info.

The attach/detach callbacks:

```
public void onAttach(Activity activity);
public void onDetach();
```

between those two methods any call to `getActivity()` will return the non-null activity the fragments is connected to. You can override them and use a `private boolean isAttached` to keep track of that call.

Also useful is the:

```
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

this method is called **AFTER** the `Activity.onCreate` method. That is very important if you rely on some initialisation that happened there.

Also it's important to remember that on the moment the fragment transaction happens, the `Fragment.onCreate` happens after the `Activity.onCreate` and during rotation it happens before it.

As a general rule of thumb I use the `Fragment.onStart()` / `Fragment.onStop()` for getting/listening to data. On those calls, all the UI have been created, the fragment is attached to the activity and those callbacks don't get called if there's a dialog/popup (pause/resume does)

Comment: just a memo: onActivityCreated(Bundle) was deprecated. activity.lifecycle.addObserver(...) could be used instead

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation:

```
public void onActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

[...] tells the fragment when it is fully associated with the new activity instance.

source: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onActivityCreated(android.os.Bundle)

Answer (score 0):

To get the reference of your activity, create a local object of fragmentActivity and get your activity reference as shown below.

```
    private FragmentActivity fragmentActivity;

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        fragmentActivity=activity;
    }
```